# HighCharts - How can I turn off the points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts. [Here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart) is the documentation. I would like to turn off those points but at first I do not know how is that called. Therefore I can not turn them off. Do you know how am I able to kill those points?

[image: I would like to turn of those points]

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Here's an example with a line chart: http://jsfiddle.net/aeZ6P/1/

Important part:

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

See also: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.marker.enabled

Same effect with spline: http://jsfiddle.net/aeZ6P/

Comment: is there a way to turn off markers on hover? Tried hover: { enabled: false} } with no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/aeZ6P/36/

Comment: @igrek - Like this? jsfiddle.net/aeZ6P/37 The code I added is `states: { hover: { enabled: false } }`

Comment: Is there a way to turnoff lines and keep only markers? I guess it will be exact opposite of this question?

Comment: @RajatAgarwal - I couldn't find a proper way to disable the lines, but I was able to hide the lines by setting their width to 0px: http://jsfiddle.net/aeZ6P/257/

Comment: @igrek, http://jsfiddle.net/aeZ6P/37 link is helping a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 96):

In Highcharts we have three ways to disable markers:

1) Disable for all series by type:

```
plotOptions: {
    line: { /* or spline, area, series, areaspline etc.*/
        marker: {
           enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

2) Disable for one specific series:

```
series: [{
    data: [14,17,21],
    marker: {
       enabled: false
    }
}]
```

3) Disable marker for a certain point:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 14,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },{
        y: 17
    },{
        y: 21
    }]
}]
```

Comment: And how to disable a figure at the point when you hover on the line for each data series?

Comment: Simply disable [`states.hover`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled).

Comment: @PawełFus thanks. `plotOptions.series.states.hover` works.  I'm glad I saw this post.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at this from the HighCharts API reference:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.enabled

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-enabled/

The options you need to add are this:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
```

This method is nice as it will work with all charts with the point markers. If you want a specific chart type, check this out:

```
    plotOptions: {
        line: { // <--- Chart type here, check the API reference first!
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
```

Enjoy!

Comment: sorry but not work on hover, on hover always have that marker

Comment: How do you turn off one marker, like the very last one?

Comment: To turn off the markers on hover, add this: plotOptions: { series: { states: { hover: { enabled: false } } } }