# Torn off point markers on Navigator highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to display point markers on main chart but not display it on Navigator chart?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [HighCharts - How can I turn of the points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642779/highcharts-how-can-i-turn-of-the-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
marker: {
    enabled: false
}
```

It is the default setting. See [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series).